# Wallet Connect With Metamask in mobile transaction Issues?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, walletconnect

***Transaction is successful in andriod mobile the hash will get and check to success but after 2 minutes we will get transaction revert error in wallet connect in metamask?*** I have metamask in mobile app i have connect with metamask in wallet connect and I tried transaction and the transaction is success metamask and I will get transaction revert error response how to get transaction  success response in Angular?

Comment: Please update the question to include a minimum reproducible example as per: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.